# Depending on bullet in a catkin package (Groovy)

Tags: ros, bullet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I was wondering how to find bullet header in a catkin package (Groovy).

As far as I can tell, I should not use rospack to do so but as no CMake macro is provided by ros-groovy-bullet, I don't quite see how to achieve this... Any suggestion?

Also, bullet seems a candidate of choice for the new buildsystem, is there a switch planned from rosbuild to bloom?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51633/depending-on-bullet-in-a-catkin-package-(groovy)/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-07**:
The switch would be from rosbuild to catkin (bloom is not a buildsystemin a strict sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not possible to depend on a rosbuild package from a catkin package. So until the bullet package has been migrated, this will not be possible, and dependent ROS packages cannot be migrated neither.

An alternative (that might not be good for your use-case) can be to use cmake conventions to use a system install of bullet.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-01-08**:
Ok thanks :)